# Quantile Function proof

Tags: probability

> Let $F$ be any distribution function and define $F^{-1}(t)=\inf\{x:F(x)\geq t\}$ to be its inverse function for $0<t<1$. If $U~Uniform(0,1)$ and $X=F^{-1}(U)$ then the distribution function of $X$ is $F$.

The proof given is by definition of $F^{-1}(t)$ and that $F$ is right continuous function, we know that $F^{-1}(t)\leq x$ if and only if $t\leq F(x)$.

Why is right continuity needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with implication $F^{-1}(t) \le x$ $\Rightarrow$ $t \le F(x)$.

If $F$ wasn't assumed to be right continuous, then it could be something like $F(u) = 0$ if $u \le x$ and $F(u) = 1$ if $u > x$. Now, if $t = \frac{1}{2}$, then indeed $\inf\{u : F(u) \ge t\} = x$ but $F(x) = 0 < t$.

If $F$ is right continuous, then if $F^{-1}(t) \le x$ (by definition it means $\inf\{u : F(u) \ge t\} \le x$) then for any $h>0$ we get $F(x+h) \ge t$. Now use right-continuity and let $h \to 0^+$ to get $F(x) \ge t$.